# How adding the current title to the breadcrumb?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I have two centent type ：Course and eLesson.

I need make a breadcrumb like this:
**Home>>Course_title>>eLesson_title**

How should I do ?
I added path breadcrumbs module

Answer (score 0):

[Menu Breadcrumb](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb)

> - Append the **page title** to the breadcrumb (either as a clickable url or    not)
> - Hide the breadcrumb if it only contains the link to the front page.
> - Generate the breadcrumb from the URL structure if content does not    belong to a menu (7.x-1.6 and older only)

How to set [breadcrumbs](http://www.cmsquickstart.com/blog/tutorial-how-work-and-style-breadcrumbs-drupal-7)

[Custom Breadcrumbs](https://www.drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)

> Many new features have been added including support for Views, Panels,
> Taxonomy vocabularies and terms, paths, and a simple API that allows
> contributed modules to enable custom breadcrumbs for module pages and
> theme templates. These are implemented using optional, independent
> submodules that depend on the main Custom Breadcrumbs module.
>
> In addition to breadcrumb visibility, this version provides an option
> permitting PHP code snippets to be used in forming the breadcrumb
> titles and paths. Multiple languages are also supported.

Comment: How can I get titile and path of Course?

Comment: I don't know how to write

Comment: like %node:title

Comment: read documentation

Comment: I think same grade content type can't make breadcrumbs,Because can't find content's title of content type from token,What do you think?